# Throw an error if a JavaScript value is not of a certain "class"?

Tags: javascript, oop

is there a way to check the type of an object in javascript against a custom type? I probably worded that wrong so let me show you what i'm wanting to do:

```
if(typeof value == "MyClassType")
     console.log(true);
```

can you do this with typeof, instanceof, or anything like that? I'm wanting to throw an error if the user provides a value that's not a class i'm expecting.

Comment: "Eww" :( If it looks like a duck, and acts like a duck, then it must be a duck. (And if it isn't, then it's <del>duck</del> coder hunting season!) I view this is a *programming error* and thus, *with a violated contract*, have no need to do anything except continuing to slog on as I would normally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `instanceof` operator:

```
if (!(value instanceof MyClassType)) {
    throw new Error("expected object of type 'MyClassType'");
}
```

Documentation: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh0zb36z%28VS.94%29.aspx), [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

Comment: what if it's namespaced? like com.example.MyClass?

Comment: A JS namespace is essentially just objects wrapped in objects. So thats still a MyClass , inside an example, inside a com.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, you shouldn't really care if an object is a particular type.  What you should care about is whether is has the methods that you expect.  In fact, it should be OK to provide any object as long as that object has the appropriate methods on it that implement the expected behavior for those methods.  That's one of the beauties of javascript.  It isn't hard types and doesn't need to be.  Heck look at the jQuery model.  They make a jQuery object support the methods of an array so it can be used in place of an array in most situations even though it's not technically just an array.

So, I'd suggest that you should test the object to see if you see a few of the expected and needed methods on it and if you find them, then merrily proceed.  If you don't find the methods you need, then throw an error.  This will catch the general misuse issues right away while not overconstraining how a client might use the API.

You can test for the existence of a method/property with nothing more than this:

```
if (obj.makeQuackSound && obj.flySouthForWinter) {
    // must be a duck
}
```

If you want to check if they were actually functions, not just properties, you could do that too.